# Confusion with design patterns "abstraction" concept

Tags: design-patterns

I was learning about design patterns and I came accross this [PDF](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/6448/f07/lectures/21/21-Factory.pdf)

On Slide 12, its says the following 3 rules:

1. No variable should hold a reference to a concrete class
2. No class should derive from a concrete class
3. No method should override an implemented method of its base classes

Now Suppose I have an abstract Class say "A". Then, I have 3 concrete classes that should implement this abstract class, they are classes "B","C","D". The issue is that D is a special case of C. D has only one instance variable more.

My question are,

- First, are the 3 rules above golden rules that guarantees a good
  design
- Second, What problem might happen if "D" extends "C" and overrides
  methods of "C" to add more behaviour

Comment: No, these aren't golden rules.  They're one extreme view on how inheritance hierarchies should be designed.

Comment: So, what do you suggest in this case, shall class D extends class C?

Comment: D should extend C if it's the case that D **is a** C, i.e. any time a C is expected, a D can be validly substituted (see the [*Liskov substitution principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth these views are far from extreme.

Comment: @Rob: Perhaps "stringent" or "restrictive" then ;)

Comment: Actually, if anything @OliCharlesworth, I found those materials the usual 'follow the pattern' stuff where the examples were too weak to ultimately make a convincing case. I don't think the first one is a real FactoryMethod, and then the refactor to AF doesn't even discuss the notion of a family of products (it notes their appearance parenthetically).

Comment: Well, rule 2 is basically impossible to follow, since java.lang.Object is a concrete class. Following rule 3 would make it impossible to override equals() hashCode() and toString(). And rule 1, frankly, is also extreme: do you use CharSequence each time you want a String variable? The PDF author acknowledges this. He says: "These are guidelines because if you were to blindly follow these instructions,
you would never produce a system that could be compiled or executed".

Answer (score 0):

If you start adding subtypes down the graph, then the abstraction becomes weakened of course. Why? Because people have to learn more, and the footprint of what is required expands. That said, there could be valid cases, though I am straining to see them in a factory situation. One possibility, to answer your question directly for that dowstream case would be to use Decorator, because it more or less preserves the abstraction but layers in some functionality that was not provided for.